# Reactjs assigning state variable to output of function (undefined)

Tags: reactjs, function, state

Using ReactJS, I have a function that hits a weather API and returns data.
I am trying to assign `this.state.results` to the output of the function however it doesn't get assigned and `console.log(this.state.results)` returns 'undefined'.

Here is the function:

```
  searchCity: function(){
    jsonp('https://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=lond', { param: 'cb' }, function (err, data) {
        return (data.RESULTS);
    })
  }
```

Here is the function that calls the function and assigns the `results` variable to the output. I've included initialState function just for reference.

```
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      value: "",
      results: "hello"
    }
  },
  searchAPI: function(){
    this.setState({results: apiHelpers.searchCity()})
  }
```

However `results` is not getting assigned.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: `searchCity` doesn't explicitly return anything, so by default it's returning `undefined`. That's why this is happening.

Comment: thanks, I have created and assigned a variable to the output of jsonp and used that instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` something from the function `searchCity()`.

Try this:

```
searchCity: function(){
    return jsonp('https://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=lond', { param: 'cb' }, function (err, data) {
        return (data.RESULTS);
    })
  }
```